# Mutable borrow occurs here [E0502]

Tags: rust

How can I correct this behavior ?

P.S Now I am trying to implement a search for the number of page_faults when using the FIFO algorithm

```
fn page_fault(capacity: i32, n: i32, pages: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut s: HashSet<i32> = HashSet::new();
    let mut indexes: VecDeque<i32> = VecDeque::new();
    let mut page_faults: i32 = 0;

    for i in 0..n {
        if (s.len() as i32) < capacity {
            if s.contains(&pages[(i) as usize]) {
                s.insert(pages[(i) as usize]);
                page_faults += 1;
                indexes.insert(i as usize, pages[(i) as usize])
            }
        }
        else {
            if s.contains(&pages[(i) as usize]) {
                let val = indexes.front();
                indexes.pop_front();
                s.remove(&val.unwrap());
                s.insert(pages[(i) as usize]);
                indexes.push_back(pages[(i) as usize]);
                page_faults += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return page_faults;
}
```

Terminal:

```
   let val = indexes.front();
   --------------- immutable borrow occurs here
   indexes.pop_front();
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
   s.remove(&val.unwrap());
   --- immutable borrow later used here
```

Comment: "How to correct"? The compiler is right. Did you mean `*indexes.front().unwrap()`?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `indexes.front()` seems redundant to me. You can simply use the result of `indexes.pop_front()` and assign it to a variable. So you can replace these two lines:

```
let val = indexes.front();
indexes.pop_front();
```

With this line:

```
let val = indexes.pop_front();
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling `indexes.front` you are keeping a reference to it (`&self`), it can be easily solved by unwraping inmediatly and dereferencing it so the `i32` is copied. Then the reference is freed.

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn page_fault(capacity: i32, n: i32, pages: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut s: HashSet<i32> = HashSet::new();
    let mut indexes: VecDeque<i32> = VecDeque::new();
    let mut page_faults: i32 = 0;

    for i in 0..n {
        if (s.len() as i32) < capacity {
            if s.contains(&pages[(i) as usize]) {
                s.insert(pages[(i) as usize]);
                page_faults += 1;
                indexes.insert(i as usize, pages[(i) as usize])
            }
        }
        else {
            if s.contains(&pages[(i) as usize]) {
                let val = *indexes.front().unwrap();
                indexes.pop_front();
                s.remove(&val);
                s.insert(pages[(i) as usize]);
                indexes.push_back(pages[(i) as usize]);
                page_faults += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return page_faults;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9492de8eb95fd707d2d330a3fe27ccbd)